# Best way to monitor Azure Worker Role diagnostics?

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-worker-roles, azure-diagnostics

I've got a Worker Role running in azure.

I'm using the standard Trace diagnostics, which i can see using the Server Explorer in Visual Studio.

However, it's very difficult to wade through, very slow, etc.

Can anyone suggest a plugin, tool, software that allows me to view these diagnostics?

Specifically, i would like to easily view all the Error, Information messages.

I know i can write a simple app which hooks into the WADLogs table, but i don't want to re-invent the wheel if a better tool is available.

I'm using NewRelic for monitoring my website, but it doesn't appear to support Azure Worker roles (only Azure Web roles).

Any advice?

Comment: Are you using Azure SDK 2.0 with VS2012? It has a great interface for viewing Application logs, etc...

Comment: @viperguynaz - yes i am. And really? You would classify that as "great"? As in viewing data for a live application - i need to run VS 2012 and wade through basically a "select * from logs" ?

Answer (score 2):

As per today (I know this is an old question),

besides relying on Cerebrata

you could be using the default Azure Application Insights that is part of Visual Studio Online (i.e. TFS as a service): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/11/13/announcing-application-insights-preview.aspx

Or to a certain extend the default monitoring tools within the Azure portal ("Management Services > Alerts and operational logs)

Also, I found this free tool http://www.manageengine.com/free-azure-performance-monitor/features.html , with the promise to "monitor live feed data and historical data of Web/Worker Role Instances" (but I haven't tested it).

Vincent Thavonekham

Comment: Azure Application Insights doesn't support worker roles

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Application Insights to monitor performance of both web and worker roles.It's less costly than NewRelic but with more features.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/

Answer (score 1):

So I had *exactly* the same problem. Getting diagnostic logs out of Azure Worker Roles was/is simply a pain.

I tried to tackle the problem a few months ago using NLog and then use WAD to copy the log files out to Azure Storage, but this approach was really brittle and in the majority of cases simply didn't work - just take a look at the [blog post I wrote on the steps required](http://www.modhul.com/2014/10/capturing-custom-logs-from-azure-worker-roles-using-azure-diagnostics/).

About a month ago I decided to fix this problem.

**Introducing NLog.AzureStorage**

The result is the [NuGet NLog.AzureStorage Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.AzureStorage/) which defines a custom NLog Target that can be used to write to Azure Storage Append Blobs natively as if they were files on the local file-system.

In your web.config or app.config file, simply define the extension and then define a new target using the *AzureBlobStorageLogger* type - you will need to specify your Azure **Storage Connection String**, and suitable **Container** and **Blob** names:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog   xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        autoReload="true"
        throwExceptions="false">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.AzureStorage" />
  </extensions>

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="AzureBlobStorageLogger"
        name="BlobStorageLogger"
        storageConnectionString="[AZURE STORAGE CONNECTION STRING]" 
        storageContainerName="nlog-storage-test" 
        storageBlobName="nlog-storage-test.txt" 
      />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="BlobStorageLogger" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

The package is currently at [image: NuGet version (NLog.AzureStorage)], however I'm using it in production with a high-volume client so its battle tested and its fast.

Once configured, you can v. v. easily download your log files through the Azure Portal by navigating to the Container -> Blob then clicking on download:

[image]

I plan on adding Azure table storage as a target at some point, but I personally don't like looking through logs in databases, so this requirement is somewhere down the priority list!

I'm more than happy to accept Pull Requests or issues through GitHub at https://github.com/nickheppleston/NLog.AzureStorage.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you take a look at [`Cerebrata`](http://www.cerebrata.com) tools - Their `Azure Management Studio` product lets you view/manage diagnostics data as well as manage storage, cloud services and virtual machines through your desktop. If you're looking a tool just for viewing and managing diagnostics, please take a look at their `Azure Diagnostics Manager` tool. They are not free though!

Comment: I'll have a look at the trial but $200 just to view diagnostics? Yikes. I can't believe MS haven't created a basic UI built into the Azure Management Portal which queries the diagnostics table. I may end up writing my own tool...

Comment: Also you should probably put a disclaimer on your answer that you are part of the Cerebrata team.

Comment: If I answered your question a few months ago, I would have certainly put the disclaimer ... http://gauravmantri.com/2013/03/29/moving-on-goodbye-cerebrata-hello-cynapta/ :)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out which one is better - Microsoft Operations Manager 2012 (with Azure template) or Cerebreta Diagnostics Manager. Have you got a chance to compare the two? Cerebreta looks kinda "oldish" and it pops some error messages once in a while...